# Exception in indexing a document in elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I have a JSON document. When I try to index in elastic search, I am getting an exception.

There is no default mapping for index1.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index1/talk?pretty=1 -d '
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("503b29efe4b032e338f0581b"),
    "_oid" : NumberLong(1182053),
    "_ugc" : false,
    "_v" : 22,
    "c" : [
        "Destination"
    ],
    "cc" : "AD",
    "co" : "andorra",
    "e" : true,
    "f" : [
        "Destination"
    ],
    "gi" : "3038999",
    "h" : 0,
    "i" : [ ],
    "k" : [
        "soldeu",
        "parroquia de canillo"
    ],
    "kv" : [
        "soldeu"
    ],
    "la" : 42.57688,
    "lc" : 0,
    "ln" : 1.66769,
    "ns" : [
        {
            "n" : "Soldeu",
            "l" : "en",
            "t" : "p"
        }
    ],
    "po" : 0,
    "point" : [
        42.57688,
        1.66769
    ]
}'
```

**STACKTRACE :**

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Failed to parse
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:509)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:438)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareCreate(InternalIndexShard.java:287)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:210)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:532)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('O' (code 79)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@5e7d093a; line: 4, column: 10]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1284)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:588)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:509)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2094)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:561)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContentParser.nextToken(JsonXContentParser.java:48)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:461)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:494)
    ... 8 more
```

The JSON is a document from mongodb. I have already installed following plugins:

```
ES_HOME/bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/1.4.0 
ES_HOME/bin/plugin -install richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/1.4.0
```

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong ??

**UPDATE** :

The error seems to because of ObjectId() and NumberLong(). However, I do not want these fields to be indexed so I have defined a custom mapping emitting those fields.
Custom mapping :

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/index1?pretty=1 -d '{
        "mappings" : {
            "type1" : {
                "_all" : {"enabled" : false},
                "properties" : {
         "ns" : {
            "dynamic" : "true",
                "properties" : {
                  "n" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "l" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
            "t" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  }
        }
      }
                }
            }
        }
}'
```

Ideally, _id and _oid should have been omitted by the analyzer but still is there any way to provide mapping for such Objects.

`ObjectId = org.bson.types.ObjectId and NumberLong = java.lang.Double`

Answer (score 1):

The json object is not correct.

Seems to be something weird going on with your _id property and ElasticSearch can't parse it because of that.

Comment: _id is an ObjectId field and similarly _oid field is also a NumberLong field. How can I go about mapping such fields ??

Comment: I dont really know what you mean but you can't have it like that. I assume it should be without those "_id" : "503b29efe4b032e338f0581b",
    "_oid" : 1182053,

Comment: No, the document structure is like that only. I just need to know how to map fields of type Object. so far, I have seen the mapping only for primitive data types such as int, float, string etc

Answer (score 0):

To remove fields from MongoDB document indexed you need to use a script:

1. Install Javascript plugin ES_HOME\bin\plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-lang-javascript/1.2.0
2. In river settings add a script attribute: delete ctx.document._id;

Fields cannot be removed using a custom mapping.